# My update query is not updating the database row

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

This query is not executing. When I run this query in PHP it just not updating the table row.

```
mysql_query("
   UPDATE `info` SET `ip` = '$ip'
   WHERE `username` = '$user' AND `password` = '$password'
");
```

Comment: What does it mean `not working`?

Comment: @ whoever upvoted this question, please read again the tooltip for the upvote

Comment: i was using password = '$password' but it was pass = '$password' THANKS

Comment: The answer here (a typo) is not useful to future readers, so voting to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing `echo` your variables..

then check your variable names..

and your update query syntax seems right..

but check again...

```
UPDATE your_table_name SET table_column = 'your_value' WHERE your_table_column = 'your_value';
```

Comment: i was using password = '$password' but it was pass = '$password'
THANKS...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `info` SET `ip` = '$ip' WHERE `username` = '$user'
AND `password` = '$password'") or die(mysql_error());

echo mysql_affected_rows() . '<br>';
```